# Use XSLT to query HTML Element using XPATH

Tags: html, xml, templates, xpath, xslt

I am trying to create an HTML document based on another one. I need to do it with some kind of templating language and I found that XSLT should be the perfect fit. However, when I try to retrieve an element of the source document using value-of I only got the text but I would like to have the whole innerHTML.

Here is the XSL file that I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="//article" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do you know the tag that I should use instead of `<xsl:value-of>` ? Am I missing something else ?

Comment: You may sometimes have problem because in html some tags does not need to be closed (eg <br>) which may prevent xslt processor to parse the html.

Comment: Yes it is actually the problem that I encounter currently

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was `<xsl:copy-of>`